# Сделать невозможным скачивание Видео файла Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Пробовал через `.htaccess` `deny from all` но понял что не подходит! 
Понимаю что видео в любом случае можно достать, как сделать так, что бы через `Network` нельзя было выдрать его? 
Как это реализовать - видел что такое возможно...

Comment: Сначала надо понять каким образом это видео получают "правильные" клиенты, что бы отличить их запросы от "неправильных". Но что то мне подсказывает, что можно только затруднить получение контента напрямую, но не полностью его закрыть. Всегда можно подделать запросы легитимных клиентов.

Comment: был похожий вопрос без привязки к cms. В общем - защитить от скачивания нельзя, но можно усложнить. Невидно через network (это же вкладка в консоли?) - это стриминг, наверно, был, т.е. поднимаете видео-сервер (например, red5, просто как пример, т.к. года 4 назад его последний раз видел), настраиваете клиент на получение загрузку видео с этого сервера и смотрите видео, которое не видно в network